# How to correctly extract a .tar.gz with md5.sum on solaris 10

Tags: solaris, tar, gcc, gzip

I am trying to extract a gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz downloaded from one of the gcc mirror site. 
In order to check the md5 signature on it before I gunzip it  I did

```
digest -a md5 -v gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
```

which gave

```
md5 (gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz) = fe8786641134178ecfeee2dc7644a0d8
```

This matches with the md5.sum in the directory downloaded from the source.

Then I did

```
gzip -dc gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

The extraction began but soon terminated with a

```
 tar: directory checksum error
```

I also tried to gunzip and untar separately like this

```
 gunzip gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
```

Then

```
tar -xvf gcc-4.9.0.tar
```

but it also ended with a checksum error.

Please How do I resolve this?

Comment: Did the filesystem fill up?

Comment: No I dont think so

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use gtar, it is usually preinstalled with package SUNWgtar:

```
gzip -dc gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz | /usr/sfw/bin/gtar -xf -
echo $?
0
```

Native Solaris unpatched tar may have problems with files created with GNU tar. See answer of @schily why.

Comment: This seems to have worked , but why the echo $?

Comment: `$?` variable is return code of previous command (tar). 0 is success. Other return code is failure. You do not need to check it every time, this is optional.

Comment: Solaris tar does not have any limitation related to this problem. If GNU tar did work correctly, it did create an archive that could be unpacked by Solaris tar.

Comment: Please read my answer for a proof! I cannot say whether there is an updated tar binary for Solaris 10, but since there is a source modification from March 2010 (see my answer), there is a big chance for such an update.

Comment: Thank you! BTW: GNU tar is based on SUG-tar from the Sun employee John Gilmore and originally written in 1987 (star is from 1982). In 1987, the POSIX standard did not have the 100+255 naming extension.  The algorithm for the 'L' extension in GNU tar is however from around 1989 written by GNU people.

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the tar archive is defective or not standard compliant.

Note that I fetched the archive as bz2 image and had no problems with using `bzip2 -d gcc-4.9.0.tar.bz2 <  tar tvf -`.

The unpacked archive has the md5 checksum: 6b8f599053a52e7c2076485d1ad3e747.

I am now fetching the .gz file, let's see what I get...

OK, here is the md5 checksum from gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz fe8786641134178ecfeee2dc7644a0d8 which is the same you see.

Note that your problem usually happens when the archive has been created by `gtar`, but in rare cases results in a `directory checksum error`.

If you like to better understand what's going on, I recommend you to use the `tartest`program that comes with `star`.

Fetch the latest `schilytools`from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/schilytools/files/

compile and then run the program `tartest/OBJ/*/tartest < gcc-4.9.0.tar`.

I did this and discovered that the reason is that the archive uses a GNU vendor specific "file type" 'L' in a tar header.

**IMPORTANT: if GNU tar was halfway standard compliant or at least halfway bug-free, this problem did not happen as the file name in question did perfectly fit into the POSIX.1-1988 100+255 name-scheme. So this is another hint on why people should avoid to use GNU tar at all.**

I recommend to use `star`.

Every single feature in `star` is fully under control of a property description structure. If you specify an archive format, `star` will never create archive content that is related to a different archive format.

If you e.g. call:

```
star -c -f out.tar -Hustar somedir
```

`star` will use a 100% compliant POSIX.1-1988 archive format and in case that there is a file that would not fit into that archive format, `star` writes a warning instead of archiving the file using nonstandard methods.

BTW: Here is the changeset, where Sun added support for this vendor unique feature:

```
changeset:   11995:caff1bd711f5 
user:        Rich Burridge <rich.burridge@sun.com> 
date:        Thu Mar 25 13:21:39 2010 -0700 

description: 
        6202362 Solaris tar can't unpack files created with GNU tar 

modified: 
   usr/src/cmd/tar/tar.c
```

Comment: The changeset shown for Sun tar went into Solaris 11, not Solaris 10, so doesn't help the original poster until they upgrade to a current OS release.

Comment: Thanks Alan for checking! Since the tar source has some #ifdefs for older Solaris releases, it does not look really hard to do a backport. It of course was better if people did publish 100% POSIX compliant TAR archives for source packages.