# How to build a gcc-4.9.0 successfully on solaris 10 sparc

Tags: linux, solaris, gcc

I am trying to build a gcc-4.9.0 on solaris 10 sparc.

gmp was successfully built and install at

```
/application/gmp-6.0.0a
```

mpfr was also successfully built and install at

```
/application/mpfr-3.1.2
```

mpc was install at

```
/application/mpc-1.0.2
```

Then in the application directory I have a sub directory called gcc-4.9.0 which also contains src and src contains objdir. The extracted gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz was moved to the src directory. The structure looks like this

```
/application
          - /gcc-4.9.0
                     -/ src 
                          - /objdir
                          - /gcc-4.9.0 // The extracted gcc-4.9.0.tar.gz
```

The  I configured it like this

```
    cd /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir
       # ../configure --build=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
           --with-gmp=/application/gmp-6.0.0a 
           --with-mpfr=/application/mpfr-3.1.2 
           --with-mpc=/application/mpc-1.0.2 
           --with-gnu-as  
           --with-gnu-ld 
           --enable-shared 
           --disable-nls 
           --enable-languages=c,c++,objc 
           --prefix=/application/gcc-4.9.0
```

The configure was successful and make file was created

The I ran

```
gmake
```

Unfortunately, this ran for several minutes but terminated with this error

```
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details
```

Unfortunately,config.log does not contain a comprehensive message.

I have been on this for weeks. Please how do I resolve this?

The config.log contents are :

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Runtime Library configure 1.0, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.64.  Invocation command line was

  $ /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/libgcc/configure --cache-file=./config.cache --enable-multilib --with-gmp=/application/gmp-6.0.0a --with-mpfr=/application/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/application/mpc-1.0.2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --disable-nls --prefix=/application/gcc-4.9.0 --enable-languages=c,c++,lto,objc --program-transform-name=s,y,y, --disable-option-checking --with-target-subdir=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --build=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --host=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --target=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --srcdir=../../../libgcc --disable-intermodule --enable-checking=yes,types --disable-coverage --enable-languages=c,c++,lto --disable-build-format-warnings

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = XXXXXXX
uname -m = sun4v
uname -r = 5.10
uname -s = SunOS
uname -v = Generic_150400-28

/usr/bin/uname -p = sparc
/bin/uname -X     = System = SunOS
Node = XXXXXXXX
Release = 5.10
KernelID = Generic_150400-28
Machine = sun4v
BusType = <unknown>
Serial = <unknown>
Users = <unknown>
OEM# = 0
Origin# = 1
NumCPU = 256

/bin/arch              = sun4
/usr/bin/arch -k       = sun4v
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /usr/ccs/bin
PATH: /usr/openwin/bin
PATH: /usr/dt/bin
PATH: /usr/platform/sun4v/sbin
PATH: /opt/sun/bin
PATH: /opt/SUNWexplo/bin
PATH: /opt/SUNWsneep/bin
PATH: /opt/CTEact/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sfw/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1980: creating cache ./config.cache
configure:2163: checking build system type
configure:2177: result: sparc-sun-solaris2.10
configure:2197: checking host system type
configure:2210: result: sparc-sun-solaris2.10
configure:2307: checking for --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs
configure:2320: result: no
configure:2368: checking for a BSD-compatible install
configure:2436: result: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/install-sh -c
configure:2452: checking for gawk
configure:2479: result: nawk
configure:2579: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-ar
configure:2606: result: ar
configure:2671: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-lipo
configure:2698: result: lipo
configure:2763: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-nm
configure:2790: result: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/nm
configure:2855: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-ranlib
configure:2882: result: ranlib
configure:2947: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-strip
configure:2974: result: strip
configure:3036: checking whether ln -s works
configure:3040: result: yes
configure:3057: checking for sparc-sun-solaris2.10-gcc
configure:3084: result: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include   
configure:3353: checking for C compiler version
configure:3362: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    --version >&5
xgcc (GCC) 4.9.0
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

configure:3373: $? = 0
configure:3362: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -v >&5
Reading specs from /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/specs
COLLECT_GCC=/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/lto-wrapper
Target: sparc-sun-solaris2.10
Configured with: ../configure --build=sparc-sun-solaris2.10 --with-gmp=/application/gmp-6.0.0a --with-mpfr=/application/mpfr-3.1.2 --with-mpc=/application/mpc-1.0.2 --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++,objc --prefix=/application/gcc-4.9.0
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.0 (GCC) 
configure:3373: $? = 0
configure:3362: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -V >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3373: $? = 1
configure:3362: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -qversion >&5
xgcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'
xgcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:3373: $? = 1
configure:3389: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  >&5
ld.so.1: cc1: fatal: libmpc.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
xgcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
no stack trace because unwind library not available
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
configure:3392: $? = 4
configure:3580: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3602: /application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
ld.so.1: cc1: fatal: libmpc.so.3: open failed: No such file or directory
xgcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
no stack trace because unwind library not available
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
configure:3606: $? = 4
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3620: error: in `/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/libgcc':
configure:3623: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include   '
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-g -O2'
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
ac_cv_host=sparc-sun-solaris2.10
ac_cv_prog_AR=ar
ac_cv_prog_AWK=nawk
ac_cv_prog_CC='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include   '
ac_cv_prog_LIPO=lipo
ac_cv_prog_NM=/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/nm
ac_cv_prog_RANLIB=ranlib
ac_cv_prog_STRIP=strip

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='ar'
AWK='nawk'
CC='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/bin/ -B/application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/lib/ -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/include -isystem /application/gcc-4.9.0/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/sys-include   '
CFLAGS='-g -O2'
CPP=''
CPPFLAGS=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EXEEXT=''
INSTALL_DATA='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/install-sh -c -m 644'
INSTALL_PROGRAM='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/install-sh -c'
INSTALL_SCRIPT='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/install-sh -c'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIPO='lipo'
LN_S='ln -s'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAINT='#'
NM='/application/gcc-4.9.0/src/objdir/./gcc/nm'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Runtime Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Runtime Library 1.0'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='libgcc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='1.0'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PICFLAG='-fPIC'
RANLIB='ranlib'
SHELL='/bin/bash'
STRIP='strip'
ac_ct_CC=''
asm_hidden_op=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
build_alias='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
build_cpu='sparc'
build_libsubdir='build-sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
build_os='solaris2.10'
build_subdir='build-sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
build_vendor='sun'
cpu_type=''
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
decimal_float=''
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
double_type_size=''
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_decimal_float=''
enable_shared='yes'
enable_vtable_verify='no'
exec_prefix='NONE'
extra_parts=''
fixed_point=''
host='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
host_alias='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
host_cpu='sparc'
host_noncanonical='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
host_os='solaris2.10'
host_subdir='.'
host_vendor='sun'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
libgcc_topdir='../../../libgcc/..'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
long_double_type_size=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/application/gcc-4.9.0'
program_transform_name='s,y,y,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
set_have_cc_tls=''
set_use_emutls=''
sfp_machine_header=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
slibdir='$(libdir)'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
target_noncanonical='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
target_subdir='sparc-sun-solaris2.10'
thread_header=''
tm_defines=''
tm_file=''
tmake_file=''
toolexecdir='$(libdir)/gcc-lib/$(target_noncanonical)'
toolexeclibdir='$(libdir)'
vis_hide=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Runtime Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "libgcc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "1.0"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Runtime Library 1.0"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcc/"

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of config.log?

Comment: sure.., I will do that

Comment: @vfbsilva The content is much not sure if it's appropriate to post everything here

Comment: @vfbsilva I have edited my question to contain the config.log

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502045/gcc-compilation-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-cannot-compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to successfully build gcc-4.9.0 . 
from this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/11502045/1363169 ; I saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16215539/1363169 which was particularly useful to this solution.

**Below are the steps taken**

**1. Download the required files .**
To build gcc, three dependencies are required:

a. GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library (GMP)   - I used gmp-6.0.0

b. GNU Multiple Precision Floating-Point Reliably (MPFR) - I used mpfr-3.1.2

c. GNU MPC - mpc-1.0.2 was used.

All these can be downloaded from here :  https://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/ , you can also download gcc from one of its mirror sites here https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

**2. Declare your variables**

```
    gccver=4.9.0

    gmpver=6.0.0

    mpfrver=3.1.2

    mpcver=1.0.2

    # where you downloaded source packages

    pkgdir=$HOME

    # where gcc will be built
    rootdir=$HOME/gcc-tmp


    # where gcc will be installed 
    prefix=/opt/gcc-${gccver}

    # the languages you want gcc to support
    langs=c,c++
```

**3. Create a new directory  where you want to keep the sources and extract the sources there**

```
     mkdir ${rootdir}

     cd ${rootdir}


    gzip -dc ${pkgdir}/gcc-${gccver}.tar.gz | tar xvf - 
    gzip -dc ${pkgdir}/gcc-${gmpver}.tar.gz | tar xvf - 
    gzip -dc ${pkgdir}/gcc-${mpfrver}.tar.gz | tar xvf - 
    gzip -dc ${pkgdir}/gcc-${mpcver}.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

**NOTE: if you have a problem like checksum error while extracting the file, refer to : [How to correctly extract a .tar.gz with md5.sum on solaris 10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/446697/293072) for solutions.**

**4. Now, move the extracted sources into the gcc source directory**

```
    mv gmp-${gmpver}   gcc-${gccver}/gmp

    mv mpfr-${mpfrver} gcc-${gccver}/mpfr

    mv mpc-${mpcver}   gcc-${gccver}/mpc
```

**5. Create a build directory and change to it**

```
    mkdir objdir

    cd objdir
```

**6.  Now configure the gcc:**

```
    ${rootdir}/gcc-${gccver}/configure --prefix=${prefix}   --enable-languages=${langs}
```

**7.  Then, build the gcc**

```
     gmake
```

**8.   Finally, Install the gcc:**

```
     gmake install
```

That is it!

Though gcc.4.9.0 was built, the step can be followed to build other versions too.

You may want to test your newly installed gcc to see if it works or not, here is how:

Create a simple hello.c file like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (void)
{
  printf ("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

then from the terminal use

```
   /opt//opt/gcc-4.9.0/bin/gcc hello.c -o hello

You should see hello filed created in the same directory as hello.c
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file claims that you called `configure` with the instruction to bind to the GNU mp library that is non-standard and thus not present on your system.

Did you do that at all?

Did you do this intentionally?

Comment: gmp was successfully installed on the system . Though I did not specifically reference the bin but when I checked the GMP directory, I noticed the bin is missing

Comment: So does it work after you installed the binary?